# Write calculated member equivalent to scope assignment

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to better understand scopes and calculated members better, so in the `AdventureWorks` database I did the following:

I wrote this simple scope statement:

```
SCOPE([Customer].[Customer].[All Customers], [Measures].[Average Rate]);  
        /* This expression sets the value of the Amount measure */  
        THIS = 999;  
END SCOPE;
```

And equivalent calculated member will be this:

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[My Measure]
 AS 
iif([Customer].[Customer].currentmember IS [Customer].[Customer].[All Customers], 999, [Measures].[Average Rate]);
```

But I am not sure how to create calculated member that will be equivalent to this scope assignment:

```
SCOPE([Customer].[Country].members, [Measures].[Average Rate]);  
        /* This expression sets the value of the Amount measure */  
        THIS = 999;  
END SCOPE;
```

Actually I am not sure how to write `iff` that will check if current member of Customer dimension is a member of [Customer].[Country]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
///Will Display 999 for any member apart from All


     with Member [Measures].[My Measure]
         AS 
         iif([Customer].[Country].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED)='All Customers',[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] , 999)

        select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[My Measure]}
         on columns,

        [Customer].[Country].members
        on rows 
        from [Adventure Works]

    ///Will display 999 for any member
        with Member [Measures].[My Measure]
         AS 
         iif([Customer].[Country].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED)='WhatEver', 999, 999)

        select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[My Measure]}
         on columns,

        [Customer].[Country].members
        on rows 
        from [Adventure Works]
```

//Below queries help to check if a member is part of a hierarchy 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//Query checks if a Member is part of a hierarchy
with MEMBER TestIFAValidMember
as 
[Product].[Subcategory].[InvalidMember].UniqueName

MEMBER TestIFAValidMember2
as 
[Product].[Subcategory].[Caps].UniqueName

select {TestIFAValidMember,TestIFAValidMember2}
on columns 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

You can also try

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.NotMember AS

IsSibling([Product].[Category].CURRENTMEMBER, [Product].[Category].[Invalid])

MEMBER MEASURES.ISMember AS

IsSibling([Product].[Category].CURRENTMEMBER, [Product].[Category].[Bikes])

SELECT {MEASURES.NotMember,MEASURES.ISMember} ON 0,

[Product].[Category].MEMBERS ON 1

FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: I understand the idea of your second query, but if I want to get 999 for australia I would write  iif([Customer].[Country].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED)='Australia', 9, 1) . But if I have hundreds of members, I would need some long OR condition, and I wonder how to check, if current member belongs to customer.country.members so that I have only one condition for all such members. Something that I could use even if hierarchy does not have the All member, some condition like IIF( [Customer].[Country].currentmember.level IS [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country])

Comment: @vldmrrdjcc If I understand correctly in your comment you have made two points  1)If you want specific values for specific countries like 1 for Australia, Canada and 2 for US and UK. In that case I would suggest you use the Case statement. 2)You want to check if a country is a member of a hierarchy for example you want to check if "TestNewCountry" is part of a certain hierarchy. Ideally this should be a diffrent question but I have edited my answer to address this.

Comment: @vldmrrdjcc you are most welcome. In fact i must admit some of your questions help refresh my MDX basics.